# Show a different div every time the page loads (not random)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a script to display a different DIV every time the page loads. It can't be random as that sometimes gives the same DIV.

I'm currently using this script to randomize it;

```
    <script>
var elems = $("div");
if (elems.length) {
  var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
    if (i !== keep) {
      $(elems[i]).hide();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to make sure the DIV is always a different one?

Comment: In order to make sure you don't repeat the last div you need to store what the last div was in some way (e.g. cookie, localStorage, etc.)

Comment: Save index on local storage...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't know anything about using a cookie or localStorage - is it maybe possible to create a sequence?

Comment: Cookie and localStorage allow you to store values between page reloads. By that you could store for instance the index of the last page load and use that to select the next div on page reload

Comment: How many DIVs are there and why are you doing this?  There might be a simple solution depending on the effect your are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, you can't use a sequence since every time the page loads its loading the same code and it has no memory of what happened last time. That's where the storage devices come in.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is keep a copy of the keep variable you get the very first time a client opens your page in local storage, updating it every time you get a new random number. This eliminates the possibility of you getting the same number twice. Local storage is very sticky and persistent, holding on to the client even after reloads and browser restarts.

Occams razor solution:

```
<script>
    var elems = $("div");
    if (elems.length) {
        var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
        if(!window.localStorage.getItem('rand')) {
            window.localStorage.setItem('rand', keep);
        }
        else {
            while(keep == window.localStorage.getItem('rand')) {
                keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
            }
            window.localStorage.setItem('rand', keep);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
            if (i !== keep) {
                    $(elems[i]).hide();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is a very cheap and easy solution. Don't know why I got downvoted!

Comment: It can be optimized since your script can possibly run forever if your are the unluckiest man on earth  :P

Comment: Whats the probability ;). Longer the length of elems, better the chances of the code running speedily

Comment: Please at least explain what your code does any why you think it solves the problem. Answers which are just blobs of uncommented, unexplained code are not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would filter out the old index first before selecting a new one.  Something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/1hdeyL4a/

```
// hide all elements
var elems = $("div").hide();

// determine an index, presuming the lack of one to choose from
var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * (elems.length - 1));

// fetch the old index to exclude it
var oldIndex = localStorage.getItem('36842935-last-index');

// excluding the old index, find a random new one and store its index
var newIndex = elems.not(':eq('+oldIndex+')').eq(keep).show().index();

// store the index for next time
localStorage.setItem('36842935-last-index', newIndex);
```

Note that the use of `.index()` means that this would need your divs to be wrapped in some kind of wrapper and that they are the only children.  If that's a problem, you can build a manual index using `data-index` or something like that.

Comment: What's the point of setting the local storage to `36842935-last-index`? why not something simpler

Comment: @Adjit good question.  This is a direct copy from my jsfiddle.  jsfiddle doesn't limit local storage to a single saved fiddle; so theoretically, if I had called it `last-index` and someone else with some fiddle that any other user had visited recently called theirs `last-index`, there could be a break in functionality for that user.  It's a problem with jsfiddle.  Because of this, I make a habit of prepending jsfiddle local storage of whatever question I'm working on with the id of the question.  I'd love to just use the built in editor, but SO blocks the use of local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to cycle through the elements matching a given selector:

http://codepen.io/jkochis/pen/RaYaBg?editors=1010

```
// elements to cycle through
var numElems = document.querySelectorAll("div").length;
// number to increment on page load
var divInc = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("divIncrement"));
// does it exist? set it if not.
if( divInc < 1 || Number.isNaN(divInc)){
  localStorage.setItem("divIncrement", 1);
} else {
  var inc = divInc + 1;
  localStorage.setItem("divIncrement", inc);
}
// Retrieve it and do something with it
document.querySelector('.increment').innerHTML = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("divIncrement")) % numElems;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `window.localStorage` in order to have persistent data.

However, you must note that the way you initialize `elems` that it is empty, so if you call the length of it, it will always be the number of `div`s that are currently on the page

```
var index = 0;
var storageIndex = window.localStorage.getItem('pictureIndex')

if(storageIndex != null){
   index = storageIndex%elems.length;

   //by doing %elems.length, you don't need to check to reset the index, your number will
   //always be in the range of elems.length
}

window.localStorage.setItem('pictureIndex', index++);

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
  if (i !== index) {
    $(elems[i]).hide();
  }
}
```